# How to query a Linkage between related records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have the following records in a table. Looking at column1 and column3 there are linkages between these data.

```
Column1           Column2          Column3
----------------- ---------------- --------------------
20003             PurchaseTrx      50001
20008             PurchaseTrx      50008
20011             ProductionTrx    90103
20011             ProductionTrx    90085
20026             PurchaseTrx      50021
20026             ProductionTrx    90145
20053             PurchaseTrx      50032
50008             PurchaseTrx      20008
50001             PurchaseTrx      20003
90085             SalesTrx         20011
90085             ProductionTrx    90103
90145             SalesTrx         20026
90145             PurchaseTrx      50021
```

How should I make a query that can link these data up together? e.g. these data are link to each other...

1. 20003-50001 and 50001-20003
2. 20008-50008 and 50008-20008
3. 20011-90085, 20011-90103 and 90085-20011 and 90085-90103, etc

Thanks

Comment: Try using self join..  refer for further info http://www.udel.edu/evelyn/SQL-Class3/SQL3_self.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Column1] INT,
    [Column2] VARCHAR(20),
    [Column3] INT
)

INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20003, 'PurchaseTrx', 50001)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20008, 'PurchaseTrx', 50008)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20011, 'ProductionTrx', 90103)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20011, 'ProductionTrx', 90085)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20026, 'PurchaseTrx', 50021)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20026, 'ProductionTrx', 90145)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(20053, 'PurchaseTrx', 50032)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(50008, 'PurchaseTrx', 20008)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(50001, 'PurchaseTrx', 20003)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(90085, 'SalesTrx', 20011)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(90085, 'ProductionTrx', 90103)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(90145, 'SalesTrx', 20026)
INSERT [MyTable]    VALUES(90145, 'PurchaseTrx', 50021)
```

Self-join query example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t1.[Column1]) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t2.[Column1]), t1.[Column2]
FROM [MyTable] t1
INNER JOIN [MyTable] t2
    ON t1.[Column1] = t2.Column3
```

Comment: The best way to thank people on Stack Overflow is with an upvote.. :)